# Change value in table on Button click in Acumatica

Tags: javascript, mysql, forms, button, acumatica

I am creating a Scan In and Out form in Acumatica as a custom screen. They are two separate screens and both are just a standard form.

They are both setup as follows: One field that is a selector where you select the Key ID of the data row you want to modify such as a Work Order. Once you click Scan In it will change the value of a field in that data row for the Key ID you selected let's say, the status field saying that it is being processed for Scan In button click and closed for the Scan Out button click.

My question is, is it possible to do this with just a click event. I mean the save button commits changes to the database but this does not have a save and is only changing one field of a specific data row.

If anyone has suggestions or can point me in the right direction that would be great! Again this is all in Acumatica so I feel the Graph or View will have to be modified?

Answer (score 0):

Once in my company we did something similar, i know this is not the best option based on acumatica way, but what we did is to execute a direct SQL query from the action (in your case the click button) to update/insert something in database. I think the best option for you would be use Ajax, but i don't know if acumatica has this functionality.

Comment: I would not suggest using direct ADO.Net as this does not handle company IDs and also opens security vulnerability points in your instance.

Answer (score 0):

In your action that is changing the status of the row, after changing the status, you can call an update to your view (ViewName.Update(targetRow)) that is used to populate the page with the information you are looking at. After you can programmatically trigger a page save using this.Actions.PressSave().